# Arrive by parameter in php form

Tags: maps

Hello hope you´re doing good, this is an old code that I found and im working with.

I have a form which I sent some parameters to google maps to get a direction but the arrive by parameter is not working for some reason.

This is the select code

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="tripdirection">Travel Preference</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="tripdirection" name="direction">
        <option value="<?= TRIP_PLANNER_NOW ?>">Leave now</option>
        <option value="<?= TRIP_PLANNER_DEPART ?>">Depart at</option>
        <option value="<?= TRIP_PLANNER_ARRIVE ?>">Arrive by</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="leavenow" id="leavenow" />
    </div>
```

these are some defines

```
define('LATITUDE', 41.8249);
define('LONGITUDE', -71.4119);
define('TRIP_PLANNER_NOW', 'dep');
define('TRIP_PLANNER_DEPART', 'dep');
define('TRIP_PLANNER_ARRIVE', 'arr');
define('TRIP_PLANNER_DATEFORMAT', 'm/d/y');
define('TRIP_PLANNER_TIMEFORMAT', 'g:ia');
```

and this is where this form is sent to be processed

```
<?php
//=========================================================================================================
//  Get Directions
//=========================================================================================================
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Must be done before any HTML is generated or coded
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Load config
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/ripta-gtfs/includes/config_init.php");

    $field_mapping  = array(    'ttype'     => TRIP_PLANNER_NOW,
                                'date'      => date( TRIP_PLANNER_DATEFORMAT ),
                                'time'      => date( TRIP_PLANNER_TIMEFORMAT ),
                                'from'      => 'saddr',
                                'to'        => 'daddr',

                                'direction' => 'ttype',

//                              'date'  => 'date',
                                'time'  => 'time'

    );


    $query_vars     = array(    'start'     => '0',

                                'dirflg'        => 'r',                             //  Use transit?
                                'mra'           => 'ls',
                                'sll'           => LATITUDE . ',' . LONGITUDE,      //  Map center
                                'sspn'          => '0.2,0.2'                        //  Search span
    );

    if( !$_POST['date'] )
    {
        $_POST['date']  = date('m/d', time() );
    }

    if( $_POST['time'] )
    {
        $valid_time = str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['time']);
        $_POST['time']  = strtolower($valid_time);
    }

    if( !empty($_POST['leavenow']) ) {
        $valid_time = str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['leavenow']);
        $_POST['time']  = strtolower($valid_time);
    }

    switch( $_POST['direction'] )
    {
        case TRIP_PLANNER_DEPART:
            $query_vars['ttype']    = TRIP_PLANNER_DEPART;
            $query_vars['date']     = date( TRIP_PLANNER_DATEFORMAT, strtotime( $_POST['date'] ) );
        break;

        case TRIP_PLANNER_ARRIVE:
            $query_vars['ttype']    = TRIP_PLANNER_ARRIVE;
            $query_vars['date']     = date( TRIP_PLANNER_DATEFORMAT, strtotime( $_POST['date'] ) );
        break;

        case TRIP_PLANNER_NOW:
        default:
            $query_vars['ttype']    = TRIP_PLANNER_NOW;
            $query_vars['date']     = date( TRIP_PLANNER_DATEFORMAT );
            $query_vars['time']     = date( TRIP_PLANNER_TIMEFORMAT );
        break;
    }

    $base_url   = 'https://maps.google.com/maps';

    foreach( $field_mapping as $get_field => $map_field )
    {
        $query_vars[ $map_field ]   = $_POST[ $get_field ];
    }

    //  Make the URL
    $url    = $base_url . '?' . http_build_query( $query_vars, '', '&' );

    header( "Location: $url;" );
    exit;
```

and this is the website

https://www.ripta.com/

I need to change this parameter in summary

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/b54E9.jpg)

Thanks for your help